# Action with pre prepered parameters

Tags: c#, events, delegates, action

I want to register some actions / delegates / Events or something like this with pre prepered parameters (no parameters on invoke).
E.g.

```
public Action actions;

public void Main()
{
    actions += Add(12);
    actions += Show("something");
    actions += Calculate(2, 4);
    actions?.Invoke();
}

public void Add(int k) { }
public void Show(string s) { }
public void Calculate(int k, int c) { }
```

Alternatively something like this:

```
public void Main()
{
    actions += Add(12);
    actions += Add(1);
    actions += Add(4);
    actions?.Invoke();
}
```

Is it possible to do that?

Comment: You could have a list of actions... add to it and then loop through and invoke each one. Something like: `public List<Action> actions = new();` Add to it, `actions.Add(()=> Add(12));`, not sure on syntax, on mobile.

Comment: Then execute them `foreach(var a in actions){ a.Invoke();}`